# PHP - Redirect to a page with confirmation message

Tags: php, html, message, confirmation

Using php, is there a way to redirect to an existing html page with a one line confirmation message.

I want to collect user info, insert it into a database, and then show a confirmation message so the user knows the record

Comment: Take a look at [**this thread**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901864/php-re-direct-after-form-submitted). It explains something very similar to what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `header("Location: yourpage.html");
exit();`

It must be used before any output, or you will get a warning message `header already sent`

Comment: That'll take me to another page, but where does a confirmation message go?

Comment: @Stylzs05. The message would be on the page the user is redirected to (yourpage.html in kukipei's example)

Comment: I was looking for something that would take me to a page that I previously had but with a confirmation message somewhere on the page. Not a whole new specific confirmation page. I already know how to do that.